# Can machine code executables be transpiled to other operating systems and architectures?

Tags: assembly, disassembly, portability, machine-code, transpiler

My novice understanding of the [different machine code / binary executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats) is that they are specific to the operating system and the architecture they have been compiled for. Nevertheless, it appears as if the [disassembling machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler#Examples_of_disassemblers) is a solved problem. Even though decompiling is still a challenge, one could wonder if different [assembly languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) and architecture-specific instruction sets are probably isomorphic between different assemblers (e.g., MASM, NASM, YASM, GAS...) and notations (Intel and  AT&T)? If this is true then we should have had machine code transpilers that would convert binary executables between different platforms, which as far as I know we don't have so far. I mean, it is as far as impossible that Apple, the most resourceful company on earth, had to develop emulators ([Rosetta and Rosetta 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software))) while migrating from PowerPC to Intel and later to ARM. Microsoft had to develop [WSL/WSL2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) to attract Linux users. Linux users have to use [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)) as some form of "compatibility layer" in order to get Windows apps running on their OS...

So my questions specifically are:

- Can machine code be ported to other operating systems and architectures natively?
- If yes, then why is it not common? (Examples would be highly appreciated)
- If not, what are the main issues stopping us from doing so?

Comment: Each of your three questions are research-level in scope, please narrow down your question to just one thing.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The main question is the title of the main post, sir. The other two questions are not independent but complementary IMHO.

Comment: If the code does not involve calls to anything not "in the code", then as long as you can keep limitations and side-effects equal, then yes. If the code calls into OS functions, then no, it would not be feasible.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen some elaboration would be highly appreciated. If I understand you correctly, your answer is yes, but if the code is not calling anything externally, like the OS-specific libraries. Right?

Comment: If you can keep limitations and behavior from one type of processor, and the code does not rely on the operating system, then you can "transpile" this onto other processors where you can get the same behavior. If you can't get the same behavior, or if the code makes any sort of call into code that we're not considering here, such as making calls into the operating systems, then guaranteeing portability is not feasible. There is no clear cut answer here.

Comment: qemu can work by translating blocks of machine code of its client into host machine code. It is not as complete as what you suggest but there is some translation involved.

Comment: I would assume that the reason you don't have many cases of porting machine language from one architecture to another is that without considering the operating system, this would be quite unvaluable. Not "**in**valuable", **un**valuable. You would be hard pressed getting a program running on a different architecture without considering the operating system under which it will be running. As such, simply a 1-to-1 translation of machine instructions would just yield you a program that technically would be OK for the processor, but then would never run on a system using that processor.

Comment: @ecm Interesting! How does it work? Can one utilize this functionality to permanently port pieces of machine code to other platforms? 

Comment: What @ecm is pointing out for QEMU's dynamic translation is the same thing Rosetta-2 does, but it's purely JIT on the fly, not caching the optimized translated machine code in a file for later use on future runs like Rosetta-2 does.  It's a standard emulation technique that performs better than pure interpreting, like JVMs use to run Java bytecode on real hardware.

Comment: Having a host framework like Qemu or Rosetta-2 involved in running foreign binaries makes sense, instead of embedding a copy of it into every separate translated binary, and takes less disk space that way.  And avoids a manual caching / update problem; users can just use foreign binaries directly, instead of having to manually translate them first.

Comment: @PeterCordes So you are saying that QEMU does the dynamic translation JIT, but Rosetta-2 does cache for later use, right?

Comment: Yes.  Qemu's dynamic-translation is only for certain popular combinations of host and guest, otherwise it's just pure interpreter (like MIPS on PowerPC I assume; two less-popular platforms).

Answer (score 3):

To other operating-systems, I guess in theory if you built a bunch of compatibility libraries that your transpiled executables could use.  But that would mean also transpiling every library used by every program, and would you do that such that they also work as native libraries for other native programs on the new OS?  Instead of *just* for use by translated binaries.  WINE's ability to use native DLLs just requires interposing its own special versions of a few low-level Windows DLLs, and otherwise doing things Windows-style.

---

Existing "emulator" frameworks like Rosetta-2 already do dynamic translation to native machine code.  In that case there's no need to emulate a different system-call interface, since it's MacOS in either case.  Very much unlike WINE, where the Windows system-call API has different semantics (not just different names for the same functions), especially when it comes to drawing a UI.

As @ecm points out, QEMU also does dynamic translation, similar to what Rosetta-2 does, but it's purely JIT on the fly, not caching the optimized translated machine code in a file for later use on future runs like Rosetta-2 does.  JIT dynamic translation is a standard emulation technique that performs better than pure interpreting if done well, like JVMs use to run Java bytecode on real hardware.

Caching the results across runs can make it worthwhile to spend more time optimizing during the translation process, like Rosetta-2 does.

---

**Having a host framework like Qemu or Rosetta-2 involved in running foreign binaries makes sense, instead of embedding a copy of it into every separate translated binary.**  It takes less disk space that way.

And it avoids a manual caching / update problem; users can just use foreign binaries directly, instead of having to manually translate them first.  The system takes care of translating them.

Binary to binary translation usually can't achieve results as good as compiling from source for the target machine, because it can be hard to know when a side-effect on a register or memory is something that some later code is going to actually read, or whether that was just a private temporary.  (Assumptions about standard calling conventions could help, but an obfuscated binary with some hand-written asm might invalidate those assumptions.)